# css when i use :hover in center image its go to bottom

Tags: html, css

i have Problem in use `:hover`

i have 3 image: left, center, right

when i use `:hover` in the left and right image its Be good

but in the center image its go to bottom

you can see the code i use here

http://www.jsfiddle.net/8Eg5T/

```html
<div class="mworks">
    <div class="img1">
    </div>
    <div class="img2">
    </div>
    <div class="img3">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.mworks {
    height: 187px;
    width: 1087px;
    margin-top: -250px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.img1 {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35904623/img1.png');
    width: 381px;
    height: 187px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
}
.img2 {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35904623/img1.png');
    width: 381px;
    height: 187px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: right;
}
.img3 {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35904623/img1.png');
    width: 381px;
    height: 187px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.img1:hover {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35904623/imghover2.png');
    width: 381px;
    height: 381px;
    margin-top: -116px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;


}
.img2:hover {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35904623/imghover2.png');
    width: 381px;
    height: 381px;
    margin-top: -116px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;


}
.img3:hover {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35904623/imghover2.png');
    width: 381px;
    height: 381px;
    margin-top: -116px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;


}
```

how can i fix it + can i make a fade when the mouse hover over the image

like if i hover over the image its fade in the hoverimagw.png

and when I pass the mouse outside its fadeout

i try to use jquery but no Luck

I do not know how to use it

Excuse me my English is not good :p

Comment: Weird.. I don't see anything in the results window of jsfiddle

Comment: i don't know why it's not show the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your width is not enough for the three images. You have to put all your div[class=img*] with `float: left`.

This is the right css:

```
.mworks {
    height: 187px;
    width: 1143px;
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.img1 {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35904623/img1.png');
    width: 381px;
    height: 187px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
}
.img2 {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35904623/img1.png');
    width: 381px;
    height: 187px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
}
.img3 {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35904623/img1.png');
    width: 381px;
    height: 187px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
}

.img1:hover {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35904623/imghover2.png');
    width: 381px;
    height: 381px;
    margin-top: -116px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;


}
.img2:hover {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35904623/imghover2.png');
    width: 381px;
    height: 381px;
    margin-top: -116px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;


}
.img3:hover {
    background-image: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35904623/imghover2.png');
    width: 381px;
    height: 381px;
    margin-top: -116px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;


}
```

Comment: thanks its works great ... mmmm do you know how to use jquery to make it fade slowly when hovering on it

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `margin: 0 auto;` to centered image between floated elements as it does not work. So you can adjust to centered img to be floated left and another way you can do is `margin: 0 {greater than right width}px 0 {greater than left width}px`
here in your example you can use it as `margin: 0 382px 0 382px` or you could just use 381px too.